# lawn sprinkler system pressure reducer settings?

Tags: water-pressure, sprinkler-system, lawn

my street water pressure is around 100 psi, my house pressure has a regulator on 70 psi.  my yard sprinkler system is directly on my street water line before the house.  I want to place pressure reducers at each of four zone valve locations as I cannot access the main line to the water yard sprinkler system.  What in line pressure regulator setting should I use?  same for yard lawn pop ups? how about a small zone with only droppers?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the particular sprinklers, but somewhere in the 25 to 40 psi range should work for all but golf fairway sprinklers.  Usually the pressure regulator is adjustable, so you can experiment to see what works best.

Comment: Yup.   Set it to 35 to 40 psi and enjoy.

Comment: I include a back flow device, a filter, and the pressure regulator along with the existing control valve.  from the street inlet one inch pipe in what order should these be?  i.e. before or after the control valve, what order?  the existing control valve is 1inch in and 3/4 inch out to drip emitters i will place in place of current sprayers,  only 4 sprayers now and will replace with a manifold and four drip heads.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I installed 1" pipe from main line to the back flow preventer. Then 1" to the main zone-valves. From there, I used 1" to all over the yard. When branching to the sprinkle, I used 1/2" or sometimes 3/4" depending on the location sprinkler, type of plants around, more water or less, down hill or up hill. There are many variables to take into consideration but the main line is 1" for having strong pressure water. I designed the sprinkler system with four zones and around 6 valves at each zones. I used different type of sprinklers. It was a fun project but very time consuming.